# JavaScript simple echo/print query

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I know this is basic stuff, but after hours of research on google, this site and others I simply cannot come up with an explanation of why this code wouldnt work. And it doesnt. Can someone please spot the mistake? many thanks in advance:

The JavaScript bit:

```
<script language="text/JavaScript">

function myFunction() {

var date1;
date1=getElementByID("date1").value;

document.getElementByID("calculate").innerHTML=date1;

}

</script>
```

The HTML bit (that definitely works and its a rather large file with loads of forms, tables)

```
       <html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<form>
<table>
<tr>    
<th><input type=text id="date1" value="09:00" size=15></td></th></tr></table></form>

<table>
<tr>    
    <th bgcolor="#eeaaaa" align=center><em></em> <input type=button id=pay id="calculate" size=15 value="Click"></th></tr></table>

<table>
<tr>    
    <th><p id="calculate" size=15> </p></td></th></tr></table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

​

​

I tried different things already, changing the syntax, clearing the clutter out, but nothing seems to work.

I appreciate any constructive comments/criticism. Thanks

Comment: try replicating your problem on http://jsfiddle.net and post the link here

Comment: Where do you call `myFunction`?

Comment: Which browser are you testing this in ?

Comment: Fix the `<th...><input...></td>`.

Comment: Use document.getElementById consistently. Only some browsers will assume document. Also the mime type is text/javascript not text/JavaScript, although that is likely not the issue. Why innerHTML on an input field?

Comment: hey guys, yeah the HTML bit is horrible I know, but its just me copying bits of it in here during work... so it is much better in the real file - i actually call the function :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two ids `id=pay id="calculate"` for your second input ..`id` needs to be unique

```
<script language="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {

var date1;
date1=document.getElementById("date1").value;

document.getElementById("calculate").innerHTML=date1;

}

</script>
```

and most importantly ..you are not calling `myFunction`

Comment: +1 Nice observation I almost ate up one of the id while reading the question @@Csongor please first remove multiple id attributes and please do call the method.

Answer (score 0):

`#calculate` (the element with `id="calculate"` ) is an `input` element. You don't set its value using `innerHTML` but `value` (like you did when reading the value in `#date1`.)

You may want to use an online HTML validator or at least a more powerful HTML editor to help you out with the code.